# Creating a file with ':' in the name

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
```

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
        return;

    if (requestCode == CREATE_FILE && resultData != null) {
        Uri uri = resultData.getData();
        if (uri != null) {
            DocumentFile file = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getContext(), uri);
            try {
                DocumentFile newFile = file.createFile("text/plain", "some:file");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the creation of a file `some_file.txt`, so essentially `:` gets replaced with `_`

What I am trying to create is a file named `some:file.txt`, and it is possible to do so manually from the Files app on the phone:

[image]

So clearly the `:` character is not restricted, moreover, I never had this problem with the old java.io.File API

I also tried

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        .setType("text/plain");
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_FILE);
```

And selected the manually created `some:file.txt` and logged the name and uri and it was correct with ':`

```
Uri: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ATEST%3AS%2Fsome%3Afile.txt
File: some:file.txt
```

EDIT:
    One workaround that I could think of, is to save all the documents into a .zip archive

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=allowed+characters+in+filename

Comment: Did you try it on Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I avoid that?

You can't. The second parameter to `createFile()` is a "display name", not a filename. What a documents provider uses for the filename is up to the documents provider. In your case, it is replacing some special characters with underscores.

Comment: As I said, it is possible to create such file manually through the Files app, and also with the old File API. There must be a way to do so

Comment: @Guiorgy: The OS maker and device manufacturers probably can. You and I cannot.

Comment: With the upcoming Android R, I am trying to move to SAF, but at this rate, the app will break for all the users